# Excel: How to increment time once in every 1000 rows

Tags: excel, csv, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I have a date-time column in DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS format. I need to increment this column value by 10 minutes once in every 1000 rows. Once an increment has been done, the value will remain constant for 1000 rows after which another increment will be made.

I tried to use the standard increment option by using time function, but its available for either time or date but not for both

```
=TIME(HOUR($L$1),MINUTE($L$1),SECOND($L$1)+INT((ROW()-1/1000)))
```

I also tried to use MOD function, but it is throwing `#VALUE!` error on 15-06-2022 01:00:00 cell value

```
=x1+IF(MOD(ROW()-ROW(A$1),1000)=0,10,0)
```

Can you please help in this regard

Comment: `=$L$1+INT((ROW(A1)-1)/1000)*TIME(0,10,0)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I get #VALUE! when i try this on 10-07-2008 12:00 or on 10-07-2008 12:00:00 .Can you please help @SpectralInstance

Comment: I've put 10-07-2008 12:00 in L1 and used the formula in 25000 cells, all without any errors, so a screenshot of your context (including row numbers & column headers) would help _immensely_

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/gQC13YW @SpectralInstance I have uploaded a screenshot. Could you please have a look

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't show a #VALUE! error - I asked for a screenshot on the understanding that it would show the error you said you were getting...

Comment: @SpectralInstance added another screenshot in the same link showing the #VALUE! error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246148/discussion-between-ann-and-spectral-instance).

Comment: If the 2nd screenshot contains the same formula as the 1st then the #VALUE! error means that the content of L1 is not recognised as a number (it should be 39639.5 as that is the number, which when formatted as `DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS`, would display as `10-07-2008 12:00`)

Comment: @SpectralInstance Thank you so much for your patient guidance. I was finally able to generate the rows. Thanks again, you saved my day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler (and more robust than using row() if anybody inserts rows at the top) is:

- in A2 put `=A1`,
- drag down as far as A1000
- in A1001 put `=A1+10/60/24`
- drag down as far as you need